# How to delete wordpress user using json API

Tags: wordpress, api

I am using josn api plugin for deleting users. This is my URL: "https://example.com/?json=users/delete_user&nonce=3c3baa1b11&id=9", but I am getting error: {"status":"error","error":"You must either provide the 'u' and 'p' parameters or log in as an administrator."}. I had also tried wp-json/wp/v2/users/ but only showing admin user(id=1) data with this URL. Any suggestion?

Comment: add admin details as &u=username&p=password

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error that you would have to provide the 'u' and 'p' parameters so that means you would need to send the admin username and password along the URL. So, the full URL should be -

https://example.com/?json=users/delete_user&nonce=3c3baa1b11&id=9&u=admin_username&p=admin_password

Replace admin_username and admin_password with the actual username and password of the admin.